# Setting FontWeight to Bold shrinks text size

Tags: wpf, xaml

I've been setting up a resource dictionary to style all the controls in my WPF application and I've discovered some odd behaviour when setting the font weight for a label.

I have to styles set up for labels, the first with normal font weight :

```
<Style x:Key="Label" TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10,0"/>
</Style>
```

and the second set to bold :

```
<Style x:Key="LabelBold" TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10,0"/>
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
</Style>
```

The trouble is that when I use the bold weighted font, the text shrinks (or the text spacing) :

[image]

I've searched about but I can't seem to see any reason for this, if anything I'd expect the text to expand because of the letter thickness increasing.
Is this meant to happen and if so is there a way around it?

**EDIT :** The window is using the following fonts:

```
<Setter Property="TextOptions.TextFormattingMode" Value="Display"/>
<Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Calibri"/>
<Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12"/>
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity what `FontFamily` or `FontName` are you using?

Comment: @MarkHall Details added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a bit of investigation following on from Mark Hall and Sayed Saad's comments I managed to work out what was causing this: TextOptions.TextFormattingMode = Display.

As Mark pointed out, the bold font text does get bigger than the normal font text when you up the font size. However, if I changed the TextFormattingMode to "Ideal" then the bold font is bigger than the normal font irrespective of the font size.

**EDIT:** Based on my findings here I posted another question, the answer to this can be found here: [TextOptions.TextFormattingMode affecting text with bold font weight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13140431/textoptions-textformattingmode-affecting-text-with-bold-font-weight)

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure what is going on, but for my guess something is overriding the `FontSize` selection for the Bold Label. I can get about the same spacing as your example if the `FontSize` is set to 11 instead of 12. I get this Image with the top 2 labels set for `FontSize` 12 and the bottom label is set for a `FontSize` of 11:

[image]

using this:

**App.Xaml**

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication1.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="Label" TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10,0"/>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="LabelBold" TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10,0"/>
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="WindowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
            <Setter Property="TextOptions.TextFormattingMode" Value="Display"/>
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Calibri"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12"/>
        </Style>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
       xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Style="{StaticResource WindowStyle}">
    <Grid>
        <Label Style="{StaticResource Label}" Height="32" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top">This is a test of font-weight:</Label>
        <Label Style="{StaticResource LabelBold}" Height="32" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,30,0,0" Name="label2" VerticalAlignment="Top">This is a test of font-weight:</Label>
        <Label Style="{StaticResource LabelBold}" Height="32" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,50,0,0" FontSize="11" Name="label5" VerticalAlignment="Top">This is a test of font-weight:</Label>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions Mark, based on what you said I had a play about with the styles and was able to work out what the exact problem was.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are not using the same font size. I tried two labels with same font size and margin. Actually the bold label expands.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look Sayed, did you have a value for TextOptions.TextFormattingMode set?