# TextOptions.TextFormattingMode affecting text with bold font weight

Tags: wpf, xaml, c#-4.0

[I've had a problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13088971/setting-fontweight-to-bold-shrinks-text-size/13123422#13123422) where making the font weight of some text Bold made it smaller than the Normal font weighted text. I've worked out that this is because I've got the TextFormattingMode set to "Display"; the problem doesn't occur if the TextFormattingMode is set to "Ideal".

For example, the following code:

```
 <Label FontFamily="Calibri" FontSize="12" FontWeight="Bold" Content="This is some test text" TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Ideal"/>
 <Label FontFamily="Calibri" FontSize="12" Content="This is some test text" TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Ideal"/>
 <Label></Label>
 <Label FontFamily="Calibri" FontSize="12" FontWeight="Bold" Content="This is some test text" TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display"/>
 <Label FontFamily="Calibri" FontSize="12" Content="This is some test text" TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display"/>
```

Produces the following:

[image: Results of XAML when running]

If I up the font size to about 14 for the last two labels the bold text becomes larger than the normal weighted text.

My question is: is there a setting I can use to have 12 point bold text with the TextFormattingMode set to "Display" that is the same size / slightly larger than than the normal weighted text?

Comment: Last paragraph, I'd like to know if there's a setting that will make the bold text the same size or larger than the normal weighted text whilst sticking with the Display TextFormatingMode and the same font size.

Comment: Why doesn't the "Ideal" setting meet your requirements? It seem to provide the functionality you're looking for... (bold text = same size or larger than normal text)

Comment: @Joe - I just thought that the "Display" mode gave better results on Windows when I looked at it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is not that the bold text is too short, it is that the normal text is too long.

There's history behind this, WPF originally shipped at .NET 3.0 supporting only the "Ideal" mode for scaling text.  This mode supports true resolution independent text scaling, a line of text will have a predictable length in inches on various display devices with different dots-per-inch resolution.  This was not received well, it caused massive complaints from WPF programmers that didn't like the blurry text that this produces.  This is visible in your screen-shot.  Note how the left stem of the bold letter m is too fat in Ideal mode but not in Display mode.

At .NET 4.0, the WPF team supported a new way to render text, called "Display".  Which renders text the way GDI does it, applying font hinting rules to tweak the letter shape so it coincides better with the pixel grid of the monitor.  This tends to stretch the letters, especially when their stem only has a single pixel.  The smaller the point size, the more pronounced this becomes.  The text is highly readable because of it, but true resolution independent rendering is lost.

Winforms also went through a similar evolution, from Graphics.DrawString() to TextRenderer.DrawText().

This [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/text/archive/2009/08/24/wpf-4-0-text-stack-improvements.aspx) from the WPF team has the details.

The answer to your question is thus No.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to have a look Hans. I'd read up on some of what you mention with regards to the Display mode being implemented and thought is might be something to do with that but didn't know what. IIRC, won't "Ideal" mode be fine for everyone as monitors continue to improve?

Comment: Yes, this will be ancient bad memory some day when everybody has "retina" monitors.  It will take some doing, they've been stuck at 96 dpi for 25 years already and many programs don't [handle it well](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/LivingAHighDPIDesktopLifestyleCanBePainful.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you've answered your question already. The answer is no. I am not sure why this is happening. I looked at it and pulled it up in SNOOP and sure enough it is rendering smaller.

It seems all font settings between 10.5 and 12.4 have this problem. Fonts 8, 9, or 10, 10.4 and 12.5, 13, 14 do not.

Sounds like time to contact Microsoft. Submit a bug.

Also, this has to do with your Windows Display Settings. When I switched my Display settings from 100% to 125%, then the issue changed. They now both look approximately the same size, not smaller.