# Differing char spacing in a WPF RichTextBox

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, kerning

I have a custom control I have made.  It extends a RichTextBox.

I have code that sets the width of the Document so that the number of chars is limited.  (I am using Courier New, so I have a fixed width font.)

This all works fine.

But once I put the control in my application, the limit starts failing.  After comparing the two, I noted that the spacing between my test application and my real application is different.

Here is an example:

[image]

As you can see my spacing for the Test App is larger than the spacing for the Real App.

I don't have any any spacing, kerning, typography or gliph settings (that I can find) in either app.  Also, I have checked every setting starting with "Font" (FontSpacing, FontSize...) they are all exactly the same.

**What else could cause the text to apply different spacing in one app as opposed to another?**

NOTE:

In case it is relevant, the xaml that inserts the control into my test app is the same as the xaml that inserts the control into my real app.  I will post it if someone wants to see it.

Comment: Did you also check for `FontStretch` and `Indices`? Other things might check are the default control template for the box and or implicitly defining your settings at the instance to see if it still does it. Also, are you sure your real app doesn't have a different inherited value via default templates etc?

Comment: @ChrisW. - I have checked for FontStretch (not being applied to my box) and the word "Indices" (or Gliph) does not appear in my code anywhere.  I have checked for any templating that could be happening to my app, but I can't seem to find anything that would cause this.

Comment: Does this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13140431/textoptions-textformattingmode-affecting-text-with-bold-font-weight) help at all. Take a look at Hans's answer

Comment: @MarkHall - that was it!!!  Post as an answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably has to do with the differences between the [Ideal and Display TextFormatting Modes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.media.textformattingmode%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). See this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13140431/479512) for a good explanation from Hans.