# WPF Formatting Issues for Fonts Between Windows 8 and Windows 7

Tags: wpf, windows, formatting

I have written a basic WPF VB.net application, in Visual Studio 2012 in Windows 8.

The program basically takes over the full screen and displays text that is supplied from a XML it is meant to fill the screen based on the screen resolution and size.

The problem that I am having is to do with formatting. If I run the application up in Windows 8 the text will fill the screen correctly.

As soon as I run the application in Windows 7 on any PC it seems to change the spacing and end up leave space at the bottom of the screen.

I have checked the follow and not been able to find any reason for it:
1. Screen resolution (they are both running 1650 X 1080 at 96 dpi)

2. Copied the Fonts from the Windows 8 install ( no change)
3. Tried a different types (Tahoma, Segoe, Century Gothic) nothing changes .
4. Checked over all setting on Windows 7 (With or with out Aero theme, with or without Taskbar)
5. This is a similar issue to what I have 
   [Differing char spacing in a WPF RichTextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14512687/differing-char-spacing-in-a-wpf-richtextbox) 
   But this still has not fixed my issue. ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.media.textformattingmode%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Any help on this would be great as I am really stumped to what the actual issues is and or could be.

here is some images of what the issues are 
http://tmblr.co/Z3zZjsgWM-BG

Comment: First thing I would do is to use [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) to inspect the running application and find out what the Visual Tree looks like.

Comment: thanks for the hint on Snoop that did help in one way I have found now that their is a big difference between the two but I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: Windows 7 Width 1584, Height 49.1433333333333 and padding is 2,0,0,0

Windows 8 is Width 1582, Height  53.1433333333333 and the padding is  4,1,4,1
 
Any ideas

Comment: any ideas ? the settings are set to windows defaults

Comment: An update it looks like it is an issue with windows 8 themes if you disable it you get the same padding issue with windows 7

Comment: I have [similar problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16195851/wpfs-textblock-differences-between-windows-7-and-windows-8). How do you disable the Windows 8 theme?